# Joining tables in SQL using substring

Tags: sql, database, db2

I am working on DB2. I have two tables having thousands of rows. Here are sample data from the columns that need to be joined

Table 1:

```
 tab1_col
 201020102012**
 201020102013**
 2010201022****
 2010201010****
 20112012201322
```

Table 2:

```
 tab2_col
 20102010201245
 2010201020134*
 20102010222022
 2010201010****
 20112012201322
 50250035102058
```

There are 14 characters (combination of digits and *) in rows of both tables. What I want to achieve using join (maybe an inner join) is that if 
Based on the above sample data, I want following rows of Table 2 be populated:

```
 20102010201245
 20102010222022
 20112012201322
```

I tried using ***SUBSTR*** function, but couldn't achieve a result as I expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are describing is this logic

```
select . . . 
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t2.tab2_col not like '%*%' and
        t2.tab2_col like replace(t1.tab1_col, '*', '_');
```

EDIT:

Based on your comment:

```
select . . . 
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on left(t2.tab2_col, 10) = left(t1.tab1_col, 10);
```

Comment: If first 10 or more numeric digits from table 1 matches with first 10 or more numeric digits from table 2, the table should be joined.

Comment: @ychaulagain . . . subsequent numeric digits don't matter?

Comment: The query above returns the output you specified. Check the [dbfiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=70b60a352979e05f23be0ff5b459e8cd) link with this slightly modified query. If you have another set of input data which is not processed correctly with this query, then please, provide such a set and result desired.

Comment: Since there will be always even number of asterisks in table 2. The first answer perfectly works for me now.